# is there any way to not open app when widget is being clicked?

Tags: java, android, widget, android-widget

I'm developing simple app that will have widget on Home Screen, but when I click on the widget my app opens every time. I just need simple widget that won't open the app or won't do any thing on the click. is it possible to somehow remove click listener or stop the process of app opening?

please provide some info on this topic, thank you.

Answer (score -1):

static var openAppWhenRun: Bool = false;

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).